# SpringMVC validation : No property 'commandClass' found

Tags: java, validation, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement validation in a springmvc app, I followed the example described at 
http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring/form_validation

When I run the app, I get the following error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'beanNameUrlHandlerMapping' defined in
>   ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   '/update.html' defined in
>   ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'commandClass' of
>   bean class
>   [training.springmvc.crud.controller.UpdatePersonController]:
>   No property 'commandClass' found

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Where is the source for `UpdatePersonController`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bean declaration for `/update.html` is trying to set the value of a non-existent property called `commandClass` on an instance of your `UpdatePersonController` class.

(If you showed us the relevant code and XML wiring files we could confirm this.)